# gRPC Quick start for Android/Kotlin tutorial - UNAVAILABLE in Server response

Tags: android, grpc

Following [gRPC Quick start for Android/Kotlin](https://grpc.io/docs/platforms/android/kotlin/quickstart/), I managed to build and run the server successfully on my PC and also to install the Android app (Connected with adb over TCP in local network, same subnet, PC firewall is off).

But when running the application, typing e.g. "Alice" and hitting `SEND GRPC REQUEST`, I'm getting `UNAVAILABLE` in `Server response`. The server is running, listening to port 50051.

I have a fully functional connection: when running e.g. `python3 -m http.server` on my PC, I can access it from my android device without a problem.

One thing I find strange is, that nowhere in that tutorial it's mentioned to specify the IP address of the server in the client code/application.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to specify the IP address of the server, we need to add `-PserverUrl=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50051`:

```
.\gradlew :android:installDebug -PserverUrl=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50051
```